# Old icon on profile page

Tags: support, design

The account list of the profile page still contains the old icon.

[image: Old Icon]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it must just be a caching issue - mine is fine.

It should sort itself out over time

[image]

Comment: I don't mean that list. I mean the short list directly in the profile page at the bottom. The list you are showing is fine for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Just checked [mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) (linked to make sure I'm looking at the right page) under accounts, and it's got the new logo.  If you're on Windows, try Ctrl-Shift-R or Shift+F5 and see if that helps.